# Columns with participants ID's and cues: separating them into two different columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, extract

I am working with R and I have a data that looks like this...

```
A              B
p1___box      11

p2___cage     12

p3___chair    13

p1___sofa     14

p3___desk     15

p1___garage   18

p2___house    07

p2___building 19

p3___street   21
```

And I need to separate them so they look like this

```
A      B       C
p1___  box     11

p2___  cage    12

p3___  chair   13

p1___  sofa    14

p3___  desk    15

p1___  garage  18

p2___  house   07

p2___  building 19

p3___  street  21
```

I am trying to use the extract function that it is within tydiverse but I really cannot find a way of correctly use it.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like `separate(A, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "(?<=__)(?=\\w)")`. You may have to `rename(C = B)` to avoid a name conflict. In the future, it is much easier to help if you use `dput` to share a small example of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` to divide `A` column into 2 columns.

```
tidyr::extract(df, A, c('col1', 'col2'), '(.*?)_+(.*)')

#  col1     col2  B
#1   p1      box 11
#2   p2     cage 12
#3   p3    chair 13
#4   p1     sofa 14
#5   p3     desk 15
#6   p1   garage 18
#7   p2    house  7
#8   p2 building 19
#9   p3   street 21
```

2. using `str_match` from `stringr` :

```
cbind(df[2], stringr::str_match(df$A,"(.*?)_+(.*)")[, -1])
```

3. Base R option with `sub` :

```
transform(df, col1 = sub('_.*', '', A), col2 = sub('.*_', '', A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option using `tstrsplit` + `gsub`

```
setnames(
  setcolorder(
    setDT(df)[, c("X", "Y") := tstrsplit(gsub("(_+)", "\\1,", A), ",")][, A := NULL][],
    c("X", "Y", "B")
  ),
  c("A", "B", "C")
)
```

or

```
setnames(
  setcolorder(
    setDT(df)[, c("X", "Y") := tstrsplit(A, "(?<=___)(?=\\w)", perl = TRUE)][, A := NULL][],
    c("X", "Y", "B")
  ),
  c("A", "B", "C")
)
```

which gives

```
> df
       A        B  C
1: p1___      box 11
2: p2___     cage 12
3: p3___    chair 13
4: p1___     sofa 14
5: p3___     desk 15
6: p1___   garage 18
7: p2___    house  7
8: p2___ building 19
9: p3___   street 21
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c("p1___box", "p2___cage", "p3___chair", "p1___sofa", 
"p3___desk", "p1___garage", "p2___house", "p2___building", "p3___street"
), B = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 7L, 19L, 21L)), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```